# need help in redirecting in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I made a web application,on local server it was working fine but when i upload it on my web server it is giving me an error.
login.php:

```
 <form action="do_login.php" method="post">
 <table>
 <tr>
<td width="256" align="center">Username:</td>
<td width="20"></td>
<td width="257"><input name="user" type="text" id="user" size="25" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">Password::</td>
<td></td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password"  size="25" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" id="submit_btn"/>
  <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset_btn" />  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

do_login.php:

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbConnect.php';  
include 'includes/authentication.php'; 

$my_user = $_POST['user'];
$my_password = $_POST['password'];

 if ($my_user == '' || $my_password == '')
    {
        $myURL = 'error.php?eType=pass';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
        exit;
    }

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$my_user' and password =   '$my_password'") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
  $get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    { 
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['login_status'] = "yes" ;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $get_info['3'];
        $_SESSION['full_name'] = $get_info['0'];

        $myURL = 'admin.php';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
    }
   else
    {
        $myURL = 'error.php?eType=wrong';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
        exit;
     }
    ?>
```

When a user signin it takes to dologin.php but dont redirect it to admin.php. On local server it was working fine for me but now i having having problem. Please guide me where i am doing mistake.

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Just to note some things: 1. Maybe it's a typo, but you send your form to `do_login.php` and not `dologin.php` (as you mention above). 2. You do know you shouldn't store passwords without hashing them into your database?

Comment: It's either the relative urls or you output something before sending headers

Comment: @Rizier123 i am not getting an error its just a blanck page

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan In this case check your Apache errors logs...

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan then maybe you indeed made a typo `action="do_login.php"` and `dologin.php` don't match...

Comment: I updated my question. here is type mistake. on scripts it is same.

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see errors. Also, do not use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`. And avoid sql injections by escaping your variables comes from outside, or use prepared statements.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Add an `exit` after you want to redirect to `admin.php` too!

Comment: Storing password as plaintext is very bad practise and should never be done. Please refer to [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for a detailed explanation to store passwords in a database.

Comment: `header('Location:index.php');`try in this way instead of using variable.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan are u sure that `dbConnect.php` is realy named `dbConnect` and not `dbconnect`

Answer (score 0):

Start your session at top of page

```
session_start();
```

if you are sending any output before session start then it creates problem in header redirection.

else you can use `<meta http-equiv="Location" content="admin.php">` it also works as header redirect.

Comment: OP did not send any output before `session_start()`

Comment: @lolka_bolka that is unsure. OP is including 2 more files in which output could be present. It also could be that `dbConnect.php` is actually named `dbconnect.php` and OP moved to a linux based server. Which in this case will produce a notice and make the redirect stop working

Comment: @DarkBee Agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Use ob_start() to prevent sending headers.

So:

```
<?php

ob_start();

include 'includes/dbConnect.php';  
include 'includes/authentication.php'; 

$my_user = $_POST['user'];
$my_password = $_POST['password'];

 if ($my_user == '' || $my_password == '')
    {
        $myURL = 'error.php?eType=pass';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
        exit;
    }

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$my_user' and password =   '$my_password'") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
  $get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    { 
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['login_status'] = "yes" ;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $get_info['3'];
        $_SESSION['full_name'] = $get_info['0'];

        $myURL = 'admin.php';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
    }
   else
    {
        $myURL = 'error.php?eType=wrong';
        header('Location: '.$myURL);
        exit;
     }
?>
```